# LuaLatex change main text font for everything a part of numbers

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, ebgaramond

Thanks the abundance of templates on the Internet seldom I use LaTeX (LuaLaTeX engine) also for non-academic texts like relations or letters.

So sometime I like to use other fonts than the Computer Modern, for example another classic font is the EB Garamond, but it has only old-style numbers.

Then the question is: how is possible to setup the main text font to EB Garamond, but keeping Computer Modern (or any other font) only for numbers?

It does not work, but ideally it would be something like:

```
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmainfontnumbers{Computer Modern}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) The claim that `EB Garamond` features only oldstyle numbers is not correct. Have you tried `\setmainfont[Numbers=Lining]{EB Garamond}`?

Comment: Ok, now I feel an idiot as I assumed Numbers=Lining was the default and the problem was in the font. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I need to reopen the question... I actually had the same problem with the classiq font (that is meant to be a sans serif Garamond...) What is the best way to proceed? Edit the question? Make a new one?

Comment: I would ask a new question

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in comment (quicker than my answer...), there are 'normal' numbers available in EB Garamond. You can access them like here:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=Lining]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}
    Test: 123456
\end{document}
```

[image]