# LuaLatex setup a different font for numbers and the rest

Tags: luatex, fontspec

This question is a duplicate of [this older question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222734/lualatex-change-main-text-font-for-everything-a-part-of-numbers) that strayed from the subject.

I would like to make a presentation using latex class `beamer`, however I would like to use different fonts than the classic Computer Modern.

In particular I would like to use Garamond as serif font and Classiq as sans serif. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell Classiq has only old style numbers and it ignores the `Numbers=Lining` option.

So would it be possible to change the font only for numbers? For example using sans serif computer modern numbers?

I am using LuaLaTeX, here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> { \usetheme{Singapore} \usecolortheme{seagull} \setbeamercovered{transparent} }

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Numbers=Lining]{EB Garamond}
\setsansfont[Numbers=Lining]{Classiq}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\selectfont

\title{Sample title}
\author{Sample}
\institute{Sample}
\date{2015}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
I really like Garamond! Classiq is similar, but sans serif.

I have Classiq and \textrm{Garamond}, how cool is that?

\pause

Really cool, but... Classiq numbers are oldstyle! 0123456789

\textrm{Garamond instead is lining as expected: 0123456789}

\pause

Maybe I can setup another font only for numbers?
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you hide numbers in the argument of a macro you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Definitely not optimal, it works on text. But what about page numbers or other automatically generated numbers?